# Loading custom font in next js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I have problem with loading custom font with my app. Here is snippet i am using:

```
/* poppins-300 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url("./poppins-v15-latin-300.eot");
  src: local(""),
    url("./poppins-v15-latin-300.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("./poppins-v15-latin-300.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("./poppins-v15-latin-300.woff") format("woff"),
    url("./poppins-v15-latin-300.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("./poppins-v15-latin-300.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  font-display: fallback;
}
/* poppins-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("poppins-v15-latin-regular.eot");
  src: local(""),
    url("./poppins-v15-latin-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("./poppins-v15-latin-regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("./poppins-v15-latin-regular.woff") format("woff"),
    url("./poppins-v15-latin-regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("./poppins-v15-latin-regular.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  font-display: fallback;
}
/* poppins-600 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: url("poppins-v15-latin-600.eot"); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(""),
    url("poppins-v15-latin-600.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("poppins-v15-latin-600.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("poppins-v15-latin-600.woff") format("woff"),
    url("poppins-v15-latin-600.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("poppins-v15-latin-600.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  font-display: fallback;
}
```

And then my fonts root:

[image]

And called it in header like:

```
import React from "react";
import Head from "next/head";

const AppHeader = () => {
  return (
    <Head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/courgette/style.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/grassland/style.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/poppins/style.css" />
    </Head>
  );
};

export default AppHeader;
```

On `App.tsx`:
import AppHeader from "./components/appHeader";
import Header from "./layout/header";

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <AppHeader />
      <div className="app">
        <Header></Header>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </div>
      <div id="modal-root"></div>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

And the result is:

[image]
[image]

What i am exactly want is dealing with local fonts that load correctly on app. What am i doing wrong ? any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Your urls for the font don't match. `poppins-v15-latin-regular.woff` is not the same as `poppins-v15-latin-ext_latin-regular.woff` (notice *ext_latin*) in your file names